# Jquery is not defined when Firebug window is open

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

I'm using Firebug 2.0.12 in Firefox 40.0.3. I am developing web pages with a link to jQuery 1.11.1 on the top. jQuery is installed on my server.

All functions and objects that depend on jQuery works OK. If I have a page loaded and then turn on Firebug to debug a function or analyze the structure of the page everything works fine.

But if I try to load the same page on having Firebug I get the typical error

> 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'

and nothing works.

I could not find this behavior has been reported again, or that is a bug. What I can be doing wrong so that jQuery will not load if Firebug is on?

Comment: strange, I have exact same versions and no issues

Comment: You should follow the [steps described in the Firebug wiki when encountering a bug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!). As I don't have this issue with the same browser and Firebug version, I assume the issue is related to your browser profile.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: thanks, now it works.

Comment: Good! So what exactly fixed it? A new browser profile?

Comment: Yes, I created a new profile and now there is no problem.